# как запустить выбор приложения на смартфоне нажатием на ссылку на сайте

Tags: javascript, android, html, вконтакте

Добрый день, сам вопрос в заголовке. Сам пока не понял возможно ли как то повлиять на это, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что это все происходит в мобильном телефоне. Ссылку на приложение в гул.плей можно просто вшить в ссылку на сайте. И тогда если сайт открывается в мобилке, то автоматом откроется и маркет.

Comment: Похоже, имеются ввиду ссылки типа `skype:`, `email:` и т.п., т.е. ссылки не на установку приложения, а на его запуск.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в мобильных приложениях честно говоря, ссылки типа skype: email: я использовал, но тут мне кажется что это не применимо. Задача такая: по нажатию кнопки на сайте пользователю отправляется сообщение в vk, и после этого пользователя перенаправлят в чат в vk. И в принципе всё работает, но на смартфонах требуется, что бы не просто перенаправляло на страницу а, если установлено приложение вк, предлагало открыть его, либо просто предлагало чем открыть данную ссылку.

Comment: Хотя изначально такой задачи не ставилось, но клиент утверждает что в ранних версиях сайта всё так и работало, и хочет это вернуть, но поскольку я целенаправленно не реализовывал этого, то не знаю что возвращать.

Comment: @ИванБатуев, откройте в андроиде настройки программ и сбросьте умолчания для той, в которой открывается вк на текущий момента

Comment: У себя я так делать смогу, но получается на то, что происходит у клиента не повлиять ни как?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно применить ссылку типа:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

или

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html)

Comment: Это не много не то, как я понимаю. Тут получается ссылка на приложение в App Store, а нужно что бы просто открывало ссылку в нужно приложении если оно установлено либо в браузере.

Comment: Тогда [вам сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791482/start-activity-intent-on-clicking-text-inside-webview)

Comment: Это вроде для приложений под андройд xml или как то на сайте тоже можно сделать?